# Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection

Tags: android, android-security

When I update my app in google play store, I got the below mail.

> We reviewed your app and found that your app uses software that
> contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these
> vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a user’s device,
> and may be considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior
> policy.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
> were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to
> use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version
> number of the upgraded APK.
>
> Intent Redirection
>
> Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.

Below is my **build.gradle** file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

  android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "......."
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.7"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
    
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.17.0'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.17.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.7'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'  // Loading Animation
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0'
implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16'
implementation 'com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.4.3'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.1'
implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:3.1.0'

}
```

I have already changed **android:exported** to **false** in Android manifest and have also added getPackageName if checks in all my getIntent() methods.

Comment: check this if it helps https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en

Comment: Have already tried this. Didn't work.

Comment: its for your app. you have not posted any code so how can i try?

Comment: please update `com.razorpay:checkout` and `paytm:pgplussdk` version to latest

Comment: My App update got rejected for following reason : Your app contains an Intent Redirection vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details. androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult. Any idea on how to figure out this? @Basi

Comment: @shakunthalaMK we updated all libraries and changed  deprecated `startActivityForResult` method

Comment: @Basi I am updating all the libraries but din't get deprecated for startActivityForResult. Can you please let me know what is the alternative we should do? I added check for Package and class name from Component as suggested by google but still din't work out. Is there anything else to be done?

Comment: my side also got same issue "androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult" I tried different way's but still I am facing same issue please can you help how to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you removed the grant URI permissions from the Intent ? This is explained in the "Additional details" section here: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555

Answer (score 1):

I'm also obtained this warning for my app in the past.
Actually they investigate your code and found this pattern:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Intent forward = (Intent) intent.getParcelableExtra(“key”);
startActivity(forward);
```

I don't know how this works, but you should simple avoid the pattern, i.e. - don't forward the intent in parcelable. May be this pattern exists in one of your dependencies, then you have some problems...

For example if you transfer the intent from one component to another you can temporaly store it in the SharedPreferences, but instead of parcelable you can use string representation of the intent, this have some limitations, but works in many cases.
In one activity:

```
Intent targetIntent = ...
String representation = targetIntent.toUri(0);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("intentStore", MODE_PRIVATE);
String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
prefs.edit().putString(key, representation).apply();

Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startIntent.putExtra("intentKey", key);
startActivity(startIntent);
```

In ActivityB for handle the intent:

```
String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("intentKey");
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("intentStore", MODE_PRIVATE);
String representation = prefs.getString(key, null);
// may be need check on null
Intent targetIntent = null;
try {
   targetIntent = Intent.parseUri(representation, Intent.URI_ALLOW_UNSAFE);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

// handle targetIntent
...
```

Intent.URI_ALLOW_UNSAFE is required if you use some flags in your intent for provide some permissions (like write permissions to document uris).
May be you need to cleanup the "intentStore" prefs in activityB onDestroy method.